# How to get total records with multi value in one filed?

Tags: php, record, explode

I use the code below to get total records group by schools type.

It works fine, but now I want the choice of school type multiple.

Previously, the field had only one value now one value or multi value as `statge= ('primary','secondary','nursery')` and different from row to other.

I try to use explode in SQL but I did not succeed.

```
$resultt = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) as total_records, statge  FROM schools group by statge ");

$statge = '';
$primary = '';
$secondary = '';
$college = '';
$training = '';
$nursery = '';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt)) {
    switch (true) {

        case $row['statge'] == "primary":
            $primary = $row['total_records']=;
            break;

        case $row['statge'] == "secondary":
            $secondary = $row['total_records'];
            break;

        case $row['statge'] == "college":
            $college = $row['total_records'] . '</td>';
            break;

        case $row['statge'] == "training":
            $training = $row['total_records']=;
            break;

        case $row['statge'] == "nursery":
            $nursery = $row['total_records'];
            break;
    }
}
```

Now not count any filed include multi values this problem.

Comment: I feel like you do not understand what a switch statement is.

Comment: You have got two syntax errors in your code. Remove `=`

Answer (score 0):

The value to `switch` on has to be the column value:

```
switch ($row['statge']) {

    case "primary":
        $primary = $row['total_records'];
        break;

    case "secondary":
        $secondary = $row['total_records'];
        break;

    case "college":
        $college = $row['total_records'] . '</td>';
        break;

    case "training":
        $training = $row['total_records'];
        break;

    case "nursery":
        $nursery = $row['total_records'];
        break;
}
```

Check the switch docs for more examples: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php